# Abort trap: 6 on sendto

Tags: c, sigabrt, sendto

On Mac OS X, I have an `Abort trap: 6` when I call the `sendto` function (few milliseconds after actually).

Here the code:

```
ssize_t writeToSocketUDP(SocketUDP *sock, const AdresseInternet *adresse,
  const char *buffer, int length) {

  if (sock == NULL || adresse == NULL || buffer == NULL) {
    return -1;
  }

  struct sockaddr sockaddr;
  if (AdresseInternet_to_sockaddr(adresse, &sockaddr) != 0) {
    return -1;
  }
  socklen_t sockaddr_len = sizeof(sockaddr);

  ssize_t count = sendto(sock->sockfd, buffer, (size_t) length, 0, &sockaddr,
    sockaddr_len); // HERE!

  return count;
}
```

As you can see, I use a custom library to manage internet address. Here is the `AdresseInternet_to_sockaddr` function:

```
int AdresseInternet_to_sockaddr(const AdresseInternet *adresse, struct sockaddr *addr){
  sa_family_t famille = adresse->sockAddr.ss_family;
  switch (famille){
  case AF_INET:
    memcpy(addr, &(adresse->sockAddr), sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
    break;
  case AF_INET6:
    memcpy(addr, &(adresse->sockAddr), sizeof(struct sockaddr_in6));
    break;
  default:
    return -1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

And here the `AdresseInternet` structure:

```
typedef struct {
  struct sockaddr_storage sockAddr;
  char nom[_DNS_NAME_MAX_SIZE];
  char service[_SERVICE_NAME_MAX_SIZE];
} _adresseInternet_struct;

typedef _adresseInternet_struct AdresseInternet;
```

It is for a school project, `AdresseInternet` is given by my teacher.

**RESOLVED**

`struct sockaddr` is not large enough to store a `sockaddr_in6` (in case of IPv6).
So I have used a `struct sockaddr_storage` to store my address.

Comment: Why would you attempt to create an object of type `struct sockaddr`?

Comment: @EOF I need to get a `struct sockaddr` to give it to the `sendto` function.

Comment: No, you need a `struct sockaddr *` for `sendto()`.

Comment: Yes, a `struct sockaddr *`, look this line:

`ssize_t count = sendto(sock->sockfd, buffer, (size_t) length, 0, &sockaddr,
    sockaddr_len);`

Comment: Sure, but how large do you think a `struct sockaddr` should be?

Comment: @EOF For the length, I use this : `socklen_t sockaddr_len = sizeof(sockaddr);` It is work well on my Linux computer

Comment: And now you want ipv6, and everything is wrong.

Comment: @EOF, Oh, I did not think about it...
So how can I get the length of my `sockaddr` structure?

Comment: You use the correct `struct sockaddr[variant]` for your protocol. For ipv4, that's `struct sockaddr_in`, for ipv6 that's `struct sockaddr_in6`, and you cast the address to a `struct sockaddr *` when passing to `sendto()` so the compiler is happy.

Comment: @EOF It is working! I use a `struct sockaddr_storage` to store all kind of protocol